# How to remove just one Body exactly in array when collision? Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection

I'm writing a game with Libgdx. In my game, i created 5 rockets (use Array) same time and a Bird (player). I use ContactListener to detect collision between rockets and Bird like so:

```
if ((BodyUtils.bodyIsBird(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsBoom(b))
                || (BodyUtils.bodyIsBird(b) && BodyUtils.bodyIsBoom(a))) {
               explosion_sound.play();
               removeRocket();
     }
```

When collision, I want to remove just 1 in 5 rockets, that one really collision with my Bird. I wrote code like this in removeRocket() , but it remove all of 5 rockets, and i don't want so:

```
    Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>(world.getBodyCount());
    world.getBodies(bodies);
    for (Body body : bodies) {
        if (BodyUtils.bodyIsBoom(body)) {
            world.destroyBody (body);
          }
        }
    }
```

Please help me!

Comment: What does your "bodyIsBoom()" method do? Seems it's flagging every "body" as "boomed" rather than just the one you want.

Comment: That method return true if Body is Rocket Type (UserDataType.Rocket). Just for rocket like BodyIsBird (just for Bird). I realized that CollisionListener class just detect collision for a body type with another,  not return exactly what body in that type if we have more than one (array body of same type). Sorry for my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this loop:

```
Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>(world.getBodyCount());
    world.getBodies(bodies);
    for (Body body : bodies) {
        if (BodyUtils.bodyIsBoom(body)) {
            world.destroyBody (body);
          }
        }
    }
```

You iterate over all bodies in your world and remove ALL bodies that are a rocket (BodyUtils.bodyIsBoom(body) evaluates to true).

You never specify the body you actually want to destroy!

Just add an parameter to your removeRocket (or removeBody) method to specify which body to remove, like this:

```
// In your contact listener
if (BodyUtils.bodyIsBird(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsBoom(b))
{
    explosion_sound.play();
    removeBody(b);
}
if (BodyUtils.bodyIsBird(b) && BodyUtils.bodyIsBoom(a))
{
    explosion_sound.play();
    removeBody(a);
}

private final Array<Body> toBeRemovedBodies = new Array<Body>();

public void removeBody(Body body)
{
    toBeRemovedBodies.add(body);
}

// After you stepped you world
for(Body body : toBeRemovedBodies)
    world.destroyBody(body);
```

A side note: As you can see, I do NOT destroy the body on the removeBody method, since it is called when the world is currently in simulation and one MUST NOT destroy bodies during that time, since it can result in unpredictable behavior.

EDIT:

Since after reading your question again I'm not absolutely sure that I fully understand it, thats why I created a small but complete example on how to destroy a body on contact:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

public class TestGame extends ApplicationAdapter
{
    enum BodyData
    {
        BIRD, ROCKET;
    }

    class MyContactListener implements ContactListener
    {

        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact)
        {
            Body a = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
            Body b = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();

            if (a.getUserData() == BodyData.BIRD
                    && b.getUserData() == BodyData.ROCKET)
            {
                // play sound
                toBeDeletedBodies.add(b);
            }
            if (b.getUserData() == BodyData.BIRD
                    && a.getUserData() == BodyData.ROCKET)
            {
                // play sound
                toBeDeletedBodies.add(a);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    Array<Body>         toBeDeletedBodies   = new Array<>();
    Array<Body>         allBodies           = new Array<>();

    World               world;

    Box2DDebugRenderer  renderer;

    OrthographicCamera  camera;

    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -1), true);

        BodyDef bodyDefBird = new BodyDef();
        bodyDefBird.position.set(0, 0.1f);
        bodyDefBird.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

        BodyDef bodyDefRocket1 = new BodyDef();
        bodyDefRocket1.position.set(0, 0.5f);
        bodyDefRocket1.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

        BodyDef bodyDefRocket2 = new BodyDef();
        bodyDefRocket2.position.set(0.1f, 0.8f);
        bodyDefRocket2.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

        FixtureDef circleFixture = new FixtureDef();
        circleFixture.shape = new CircleShape();
        ((CircleShape) circleFixture.shape).setRadius(0.02f);

        FixtureDef rocketFixture = new FixtureDef();
        rocketFixture.shape = new PolygonShape();
        ((PolygonShape) rocketFixture.shape).set(new float[]
        { 0, 0, 0.01f, 0, 0.01f, 0.05f, 0, 0.05f, 0, 0 });

        BodyDef bodyDefFloor = new BodyDef();
        bodyDefFloor.position.set(-100, 0);
        bodyDefFloor.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;

        FixtureDef lineFixture = new FixtureDef();
        lineFixture.shape = new EdgeShape();
        ((EdgeShape) lineFixture.shape).set(Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(200, 0));

        Body floor = world.createBody(bodyDefFloor);
        floor.createFixture(lineFixture);

        Body bird = world.createBody(bodyDefBird);
        bird.createFixture(circleFixture);
        bird.setUserData(BodyData.BIRD);

        Body rocket1 = world.createBody(bodyDefRocket1);
        rocket1.createFixture(rocketFixture);
        rocket1.setUserData(BodyData.ROCKET);

        Body rocket2 = world.createBody(bodyDefRocket2);
        rocket2.createFixture(rocketFixture);
        rocket2.setUserData(BodyData.ROCKET);

        renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();

        world.setContactListener(new MyContactListener());

        rocketFixture.shape.dispose();
        circleFixture.shape.dispose();
        lineFixture.shape.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        world.step(1 / 60f, 8, 3);

        renderer.render(world, camera.combined);

        for (Body body : toBeDeletedBodies)
        {
            world.destroyBody(body);
        }

        toBeDeletedBodies.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        renderer.dispose();
        world.dispose();
    }
}
```

When you run this example you see a circle (bird) on a floor and two rectangles (rockets) falling down. One of the rectangles hits the circle and is thus destroyed, the other rectangle is NOT destroyed.

Comment: It's really work guy. Thank you so much, so much and so much. And I'm so excited when you can understand my English. Haha. Thanks.